# How do I load an Activity from within a Library?

Tags: android

I've got a projected marked as "Is Library" - it has all the activities. I've got a new Android project that references this library.  How do I mark one of my library's activities as the first one that starts up?

EDIT

My original manifest looks like this:

```
<activity android:name=".Welcome" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

All my activities are in the package `com.rjs.animator`.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you AndroidManifest.xml contain those Activity tag and reference to the correct namespace/class within your Library, you should be good to go.

Comment: I messed around with this... the app crashes with a missing activity error. I edited my question with the specifics of my project, perhaps you could help out with my syntax?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add all activities and other components to the new Android project's manifest, with whatever `<intent-filter>` elements you want. Just put the standard `MAIN`/`LAUNCHER` `<intent-filter>` on whichever activity you want.

Comment: Aren't the `intent-filter` lines pretty generic? I'm not sure what I'd change them to.

Comment: @Chu: It's not a question of "changing" the filters. They just need to be in your hosting project, not the library.